# DOM help - jsoup nextSibling

Tags: jsoup

What I'm trying to do seems so simple to me but I'm struggling far more than I should be.  I have a document which contains the following:

```html
<h2>First Heading</h2>
<table>
    <div class="title">First Subheading One</div>
    <div class="title">First Subheading Two</div>
    <div class="title">First Subheading Three</div>
</table>

<h2>Second Heading</h2>
<table>
    <div class="title">Second Subheading One</div>
    <div class="title">Second Subheading Two</div>
    <div class="title">Second Subheading Three</div>
</table>

<h2>Third Heading</h2>
<table>
    <div class="title">Third Subheading One</div>
    <div class="title">Third Subheading Two</div>
    <div class="title">Third Subheading Three</div>
</table>
```

Using doc.select("h2") gives me all the headings, as expected.  Using doc.select("div.title") gives me all the subheadings, also as expected.  What I'm trying to do is iterate through the returned h2 elements, and within them, then iterate through the returned div.title elements - I've tried many things, and I'm not new to coding at all (new to jsoup, however) but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this.

```java
Headings = httpDoc.select("h3");
for(Element Headings : heading) {
    // something with heading.nextSibling here
}
```

Should there be something I can do (eg. nextSibling) which gives me the  node?  And from there I can do another select("div.title") and iterate through those to grab the subheadings?

Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way?  Apologies if this seems silly - feeling a little stupid as I've been coding for more years than I'm willing to admit, but have never had to deal with DOM (always been a Win32 guy.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### My understanding !!

What I understood from your question is that you are trying to get the `h2` tag and then for each `heading <h2>` your are trying to get the corresponding `div.title` inside the table.

### Your Mistakes

1. In the provided code snippet your trying to get the ***`h3`*** instead of ***`h2`***, which you don't have in your HTML code.
2. Secondly, the HTML snippet is a buggy one **because** as per W3 standards a `<table>` should have a `<tr>` & `<td>` (I think `<td>` is optional, please check the W3 page). So when you are parsing the HTML snippet, **jSoup** just ***`prunes/removes`*** the ill-formed `<table>`

### Expected output as per my understanding of your problem !!

```
The header is: First Heading
The div content is: First Subheading One
The div content is: First Subheading Two
The div content is: First Subheading Three
========== +_+ ===========
The header is: Second Heading
The div content is: Second Subheading One
The div content is: Second Subheading Two
The div content is: Second Subheading Three
========== +_+ ===========
The header is: Third Heading
The div content is: Third Subheading One
The div content is: Third Subheading Two
The div content is: Third Subheading Three
========== +_+ ===========
```

### Code for the above output !!

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JSoupTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "<h2>First Heading</h2>";
        s += "<table><tr><td>";
        s += "<div class='title'>First Subheading One</div>";
        s += "<div class='title'>First Subheading Two</div>";
        s += "<div class='title'>First Subheading Three</div>";
        s += "</table>";

        s += "<h2>Second Heading</h2>";
        s += "<table><tr><td>";
        s += "<div class='title'>Second Subheading One</div>";
        s += "<div class='title'>Second Subheading Two</div>";
        s += "<div class='title'>Second Subheading Three</div>";
        s += "</td></tr></table>";

        s += "<h2>Third Heading</h2>";
        s += "<table><tr><td>";
        s += "<div class='title'>Third Subheading One</div>";
        s += "<div class='title'>Third Subheading Two</div>";
        s += "<div class='title'>Third Subheading Three</div>";
        s += "</td></tr></table>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);

        Elements h_2 = doc.select("h2");
        for(int i=0; i<h_2.size(); i++)
        {
            Element e = h_2.get(i);
            System.out.println("The header is: " + e.ownText());

            Element nextSib = e.nextElementSibling();

            Elements divs = nextSib.select("div.title");            
            for(int j=0; j<divs.size(); j++)
            {
                Element d = divs.get(j);
                System.out.println("The div content is: " + d.ownText());
            }

            System.out.println("========== +_+ ===========");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much!  My problem was that I was trying to get the sibling of the wrong element.  Your example made me realise my mistake and my code is now working as expected.  Thank you!